# js same onclick for different divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

ik, that this is probably simple, but i can't figure it out.

I have 2 different divs `.div1` and `.div2` How can I add them same function in (2in1)? So i don't have to write it like this:

```
$(".div1").click(function(){
        $(".webdesign-karta").css("margin-left", "40%");
    });

$(".div2").click(function(){
        $(".webdesign-karta").css("margin-left", "40%");
    });
```

But I could write it somehow like this (I want to avoid long code):

```
$(".div1", ".div2").click(function(){
        $(".webdesign-karta").css("margin-left", "40%");
    });
```

Thanks everyone, have a nice day!

Comment: `$(".div1, .div2")` - https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it!

```
$(".div1, .div2").click(function(){
        $(".webdesign-karta").css("margin-left", "40%");
    });
```

if you want to be more generic you can do it on the div selector itself:

```
$("div").click(function(){
        $(".webdesign-karta").css("margin-left", "40%");
    });
```

or create a CSS style rule and add it on the click - which is better because it doesnt add an inline style rule.:

```
//css
.moveMargin{margin-left:40%}

//js
$(".div1, .div2").click(function(){
        $(".webdesign-karta").addClass("moveMargin");
    });
```

Comment: Oh, that's painful! Thanks, got it! Greetings!